# Magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.5 upgrade for website on same server

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.3

I have four Magento websites are running with 2.3.2 version on the same server.

Now I'm planning to upgrade only 2 sites. How can we safely upgrade without disturbing other websites?

Comment: Why not download, upgrade, and upload ?? Or just upgrade the sites you want to upgrade.No effect on other sites if they are not from one instance.

Comment: You mean single Magento Installation and 4 website setup or all 4 websites having separate Magento Installation?

Comment: Individual Magento instance for websites @RamSharma

Comment: @Antony in this case just take backup of DB & files and upgrade it, No harm to do that